# Entity Framework, when I run enable-migrations, it doesn't create folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am getting errors as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Also I examine my nuget package (for version), Entity Framework packages too.

I asked chatgpt for help, and I did what it want, but it doesn't work.

This is the error:

```
PM> enable-migrations

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Özel durum bir çağırma hedefi tarafından oluşturuldu. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'part22TravelTripProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' dosyasını veya bütünleştirilmiş kodunu ya da bağımlılıklarından birini yükleyemedi. İşlem desteklenmiyor. (HRESULT özel durum döndürdü: 0x80131515) ---> System.NotSupportedException: Bir bütünleştirilmiş kod, önceki .NET Framework sürümlerinde korumalı alana alınmasına neden olacak bir ağ konumundan yüklenmeye çalışıldı. Bu .NET Framework sürümü CAS ilkesini varsayılan olarak etkinleştirmez, bu nedenle söz konusu yükleme tehlikeli olabilir. Bu yüklemenin bütünleştirilmiş kodu korumalı alana alması amaçlanmıyorsa, lütfen loadFromRemoteSources anahtarını etkinleştirin. Daha fazla bilgi için bkz. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569.

   --- İç özel durum yığını izlemesinin sonu ---
   konum: System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   konum: System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   konum: System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   konum: System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor..ctor(String assemblyFile, IDictionary`2 anonymousArguments)
   --- İç özel durum yığını izlemesinin sonu ---
   konum: System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   konum: System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   konum: System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   konum: System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   konum: System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   konum: System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   konum: System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   konum: System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   konum: System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   konum: System.Data.Entity.Tools.AppDomainExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String dataDirectory, String configurationFile, String rootNamespace, String language)
   konum: System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
   konum: System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.MigrationsEnableCommand.Execute()
   konum: Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   konum: System.Data.Entity.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Özel durum bir çağırma hedefi tarafından oluşturuldu.
```

Comment: Running "enable-migrations" doesn't create any folders - only once you actually **create** a migration by using "add-migration" will a folder be created (if not present already)

Comment: Please edit the question to include the error message as text, not as an image.

Comment: When I type enable-migrations, it should create a configurations class in the migrations folder. but when i type i get this error

Comment: ChatGPT doesn't "know" anything and one should never assume an answer from ChatGPT is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load an assembly from a remote location but it is not allowed in your configs. To fix it, set `<loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true">`. Here is a full example:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Please see [MS docs on the loadFromRemoteSources element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd409252(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for more details.

Comment: ı trıed enabled= true from using cmd :Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\Security\TrustManager\PromptingLevel" -Name "Internet" -Value "Enabled"                         , ı wıll try your answer too thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe it can't help you. Click on your project and turn off the Invariant Globalization.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znYjX.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and paste the code as text, not as an image. Also, please explain why this makes difference.

Comment: I don't understand what to do, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).